# Space-themed movie about protagonists on a small ship

Tags: identify-this-movie

I can only remember bits and pieces of this film, the info I'm giving may or may appear in that order but here it goes:

- takes place in space (probably in the future)
- very huge space ships which are literally the home for many people
- protagonists have a small ship though.
- possible released in the last decade. decently cast.
- there's one computer guy who has an robot girlfriend. this character appears after some time into the film. He's sought by the protagonist group for help... he agrees to help but betrays them by giving out their location to antagonist group who then kill him.
- the protagonist group goes to a planet (earth?) to retrieve something and the villain group don't want them to. On this planet all the people and life has died instantly... like in a 'snap'. When the hero group gets here, they see dead decomposed bodies. the scene is like they all died when they were just going about their everyday lives. Cause of death is probably a bio weapon.

The last two points are all I can remember. Nothing else is coming to my mind. It's been bugging me since days and I had no luck with Google.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These plot points are found in [Serenity](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0379786/combined) from 2005.

> In the future, a spaceship called Serenity is harboring a passenger with a deadly secret. Six rebels on the run. An assassin in pursuit. When the renegade crew of Serenity agrees to hide a fugitive on their ship, they find themselves in an awesome action-packed battle between the relentless military might of a totalitarian regime who will destroy anything - or anyone - to get the girl back and the bloodthirsty creatures who roam the uncharted areas of space. But, the greatest danger of all may be on their ship.

The crew comes across [Mr. Universe](https://i2.wp.com/media.boingboing.net/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/MIS_13.8h1.jpg), a hacker who has a female love bot and betrays them (and is killed by the antagonists - the Operative - he betrayed them to), and also a planet full of dead bodies. The film was a continuation of the show [Firefly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firefly_%28TV_series%29). Here's the trailer:

Comment: yes this is it. thanks a lot. not even one cast member came to my mind when tried to google, not even Chiwetel Ejiofor.

Comment: @Jay Kamma  you also might want to check [the series](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0303461/) out

Comment: I second the suggestion by @madmada to see the TV series first (it's just one short season) to get the best out of the characterization and stories.